# Visual Studio 2010: strange linker error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have the following code in my project:

SomeCode.h :

```
#pragma once 

#include "defines.h"

void Function1(int *param1, float *param2, int count);
void Function2(int *param1, float *param2);
void Function3(int *param1, float *param2);
```

SomeCode.cpp :

```
#include "SomeCode.h"

void Function1(int *param1, float *param2, int count)
{
//implementation
}

void Function2(int *param1, float *param2)
{
//implementation
}

void Function3(int *param1, float *param2)
{
//implementation
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "SomeCode.h"

int main()
{
// some Function1, Function2, Function3 usage
}
```

All the above files are in the same folder.

The solution compiles fine, but i get Function1, Function2, Function3 unresolved external errors. Cleaning and building again doesn't help. However a magical workaround to make it building successfully is the following:
1) comment all the lines in SomeCode.cpp
2) build the solution and get the same linker errors
3) uncomment the lines
4) build again

I encounter the same problem from time to time when I change something in my project (adding new files, making changes to existing once). However this happens not on a regular basis, so I can't tell precisely when the problem appear.

Any ideas what might cause these troubles?

Comment: Did you add the new object file in with the linking step?

Comment: @user973572 I'm not sure that I completely understand your question... There is a dependency on another library. This library is built from source code in another project. I can't exactly say whether my problems started before I hooked up this library or after. But I can definitely say the problem persisted after i hooked the library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to add a

> `#include "somecode.h`

In somecode.cpp ?

Comment: oh... sure I do! I've edited my question. Thanks for pointing out at it!